# PHP createFromFormat not behaving like expected

Tags: php, datetime

I have the following php cli code:

```
var_dump(\DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z', '2001-08-26T00:00:00.000Z', new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam')));
```

The result is:

```
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2001-08-26 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "Europe/Amsterdam"
}
```

Why isn't there 2 hours being added to the date? According to docs, timezone should only be ingored in case of  `UNIX timestamp (e.g. 946684800) or specifies a timezone (e.g. 2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00).`

Comment: _"Why isn't there 2 hours being added to the date?"_ - why _should_ there be?

Comment: Well Amsterdam is +1 GMT plus add 1 hour daylight savings?

Comment: The `Z` in your time format is UTC, which overrides the Amsterdam timezone. -- `The timezone parameter and the current timezone are ignored when the datetime parameter either contains a UNIX timestamp (e.g. 946684800) or specifies a timezone (e.g. 2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00).` [(src)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimeimmutable.createfromformat.php)

Comment: _"Well Amsterdam is +1 GMT plus add 1 hour daylight savings?"_ - when someone says to you, "it is midnight right now", while you are in Amsterdam - are you then going and adding two hours in your mind ...? You are supplying a date with the time component being midnight, and that you want the Amsterdam time zone. And you _got_ a date object, that has it's time set as midnight, in the Amsterdam time zone ...

Comment: Where did you read about bout `Z` format character in the documention?

Comment: @Zhorov `Z` is not a format character in there, it has been escaped with a backslash. This matches the _literal_ `Z` character at the end of their input date value.

Comment: @CBroe, you are right, I missed the escape character.

Comment: I see, I never considered the Z being read as a timezone, I assumed it was without timezone this way. That clears it up

Comment: `Z` is for "Zulu", which is a military designation for UTC.

Answer (score 0):

Happy to be corrected, but I always thought the DateTimeZone parameter was that which you were supplying. Then you would need to modify it using an additional set to the TimeZone you'd like.

For example:

```
<?php
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z', '2001-08-26T00:00:00.000Z');
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam'));
var_dump($date);
?>
```

Comment: This answer is still incorrect as the timezone specifier in the format is escaped, which will cause the date to be interpreted as the _default_ timezone, not Z/UTC as specified in the date string. Replace `\Z` with `O` and it becomes correct.